# Isometric metric spaces and its properties

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, isometry

Let $(X,d_x)$ and $(Y,d_y)$ two isometric metric spaces .

If one of them is connected or compact , should the other have the same property ?

What are the things if one of them satisfies them the other also satisfies them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isometries are continuous, and the continuous images of connected and compact sets are connected and compact, respectively.

Off the top of my head, isometries also preserve extremal points, and linear isometries between inner product spaces preserve angles. A deep fact is that if $X$ and $Y$ are compact metric spaces, then $C(X)$ and $C(Y)$ are isometric if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic (this is Banach-Stone theorem).